# Add font on pdf report with fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, fonts, report

I'm generating a pdf report with fpdf on php. I need to add Century Gothic font for this document.

I think that i would have to do something like this :

```
$pdf->AddFont('CenturyGothic','','century.php');
$pdf->SetFont('CenturyGothic','',12);
```

But this don't work and i can't find the file with the kind of letter for this library. Help please.

Comment: Have you read the FPDF tutorial on this? http://fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

Go to http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/index.php

Convert your .ttf file

Download the .php and the .z file

Add these files to the following folder: fpdf/font
(This is the default folder structure that you need to download in order for your fpdf to work)

This is the code I have used in my file:

```
$fpdf->AddFont('Gotham','','Gotham-Book.php');
$fpdf->SetFont('Gotham','',11);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's [the relevant tutorial](http://fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm).

I'm guessing that you're forgetting to do `MakeFont` before you try to add the font, specifically:

```
<?php
require('makefont/makefont.php');

MakeFont('c:\\Windows\\Fonts\\comic.ttf','cp1252');
?>
```

Once you have the font definition files generated (usually `.z` extension) then `AddFont` should work.